# setEmptyView() on FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, fragmentstatepageradapter

Is there a nice and easy way to set an empty View on a FragmentStatePagerAdapter?
A bit like the same way we do on ListView.setEmptyView(view).

Indeed, I'm working with a FragmentStatePagerAdapter, with Data coming from a CursorLoader and it's not as easy.

Cheers

Comment: If you are saying that you want to show something special when you have no pages to show, `setVisibility(View.GONE)` on the `ViewPager` and `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` on your previously-`GONE` empty view. Or, configure your `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to return one page that is the empty view. Beyond that, `ViewPager` has no concept of an empty view.